# Explicit context menu invocation works from time to time in Android

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to show a context menu when a user presses Menu button. I found and use the following code snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
  if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
  {
    ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewById(IMAGE_ID);
    Log.v("me", "menu " + v.toString());
    openContextMenu(v);
  }
  return true; // return false; doesn't work either
}
```

The view is, of course, registered for context menu, and it works ok by long touches. The problem is that the abovementioned code works only from time to time. That is the log messages are always fired, when I press Menu button, but the context menu shows up in very rare cases. The only case when it shows ok, is just after the application start. In other words, only first attempt is successfull, and all the others work occasionally, but mostly don't. The view is not changed and always found, otherwise it could produce such problem and exception in logging line.

Comment: "I want to show a context menu when a user presses Menu button" -- please do not do this. For starters, there are millions of devices that do not have a MENU button. Please allow the MENU button, where it exists, to work the normal action bar or options menus.

Comment: @CommonsWare. I will do it, if someone can help me to solve the problem ;-). I know that Menu button is missing on some devices, but if it's present, the user normally is accustomed to press it and get feedback. As for action bar and options menu, we could discuss this design question in other appropriate place where it will not be offtopic. Just let me know.

Comment: "but if it's present, the user normally is accustomed to press it and get feedback" -- no, the user normally is accustomed to press it and get the action bar overflow or an options menu. The user normally is not accustomed to press it and get anything else. That has been a UX anti-pattern since Android's outset. Please allow the MENU button, where it exists, to work the normal action bar or options menus. As a side benefit, you can avoid the hacks that you are having problems with in this question.

Comment: @CommonsWare, alas, this is offtopic here, I can't discuss and can't accept it. I see your point, but it's too rigid and forces general (and not always acceptable) UX principles on a specific application. Even if you name this a hack, it makes me think there is a bug in Android, because the code as is should work. I'm asking for a help to solve the problem. As for UX discussions, please suggest another place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a bug in `onCreateContextMenu` which prevented the context menu from showing up time to time. In fact it did not populate the menu with items, and an empty menu is skipped by design in Android's core. Now it works as expected.